# HTML and CSS Images Not Loading

Tags: html, css, image

Hi I have been stuck for a good amount of time with what I believe is a file path issue.  I am creating a simple layout with a background image, the background image loaded as a http url but once I saved the file to my computer and altered the image I cannot get it to load.  the file structure is as follows : 
  new project/css/images/index.html

the code:

```
header {
    height: 450px;
    background-image: url('../images/bg_blur.png'), center, center;
    background-size: cover

}
```

I have run into the same issue with my logo image as well.

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="images/icon.svg">
</div>
```

As a novice, I have spent over a day trouble shooting this issue double and triple checking my paths, trying different methods.  I have read multiple stack overflow answers and still cannot figure this out, I apologize for re-posting but I am at a loss.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: clarify your file structure

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the exact same path then make sure that the filename of the images is exactly the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

The **background-image** *property enables you to provide an image for the
background,
it accepts only uri()* / none values, you can't specified several values.

Instead try to use **background** shorthand property like this:

```
header {
background: url(../images/bg_blur.png) center center;
}
```

background shorthand property can accepts several values

<’background-color’> || <’background-image’> || <’backgroundrepeat’>
|| <’background-attachment’> || <’background-position’>

Initial value: n/a

the values should be separated by white spaces .

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Konrud said but also, you're missing a semicolon on the end of the final CSS rule you put, the background-size one.

```
background-size: cover
```

should be

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: thank you for the responses, I used the short hand and added the semi-colon.  I also went back to check my file structure again when I thought to open the background image in safari and pasting that location from the url bar.  This worked to get the background image to show but still nothing on the svg.